# Sqlite group_concat function

Tags: database, sqlite

According to documentation `The order of the concatenated elements is arbitrary`. is there any way to get sorted data(to get data according to the data source) rather than random choice ?

Answer (score 2):

Some other databases allow an `ORDER BY` clause in there, but SQLite just uses whatever order the records happen to be read from the table/index/subquery.

If you are using one fixed version of SQLite, and if your database schema does not change, and if you never re-execute `ANALYZE`, and if your SQL query stays the same, then the order will stay the same.

However, these conditions are hard to guarantee.
Usually, it would be a better idea to not aggregate that field and to use an `ORDER BY` clause instead, or to use a separator and sort the values in your code.